# Jasmine + Chutzpah: Expected undefined to be equal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, jasmine, chutzpah

I'm new in this angular world, so sorry if this is so basic, but I'm not getting it

I'm having this error whenever I try to run my jasmine tests

My controller is defined this way:

```
angular.module('Module',[]).controller('GACtrl', ['GASvc', '$scope', GACtrl]);

function GACtrl(SasService, $scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.prueba = 20;
```

Jasmine test:

```
describe("Tests", function () {
var $scope, ctrl;
var svcMock;

beforeEach(function(){
    svcMock = jasmine.createSpyObj("GACtrl", ["GACtrl"]);

    module('Module');

    inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    });
});

it(", should show the connection between controller and tests", function () {
    expect($scope.prueba).toEqual(20);
})
```

Visual Studio and Chutzpah keep showing me that error, this porject had a service.js file, I only want to test controller functions, tests are in a separate VS project from Controller and Service.

Thanks and sorry for the bad English!

Comment: What version of angular are you using? What does your chutzpah.json file look like? Have you looked at the samples on https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah

Comment: @MatthewManela Angularjs v1.5.8, I don't have  a chutzpah.json file, installed Chutzpah as an VS extension, should I have one? I take a look on many samples, but I'm not really understanding the load of service and controllers and how to use it and (in this case at least), call controller properties.

Comment: I can't help you with Angular too much but I can point you to the Angular samples (https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/tree/master/Samples/Angular) I include with Chutzpah. Does that help?